# Bootstrap how to hide column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi I want to hide some columns on mobile but everything i tried has failed. I have tried hidden-xs and visiable-lg but still cant do it. What i want to do is hide the column name Saat when the browser is on mobile.

[This is what i am getting on mobile which is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtTo7.png)

[This is what i get on mobile which i dont want it. I dont want the "Saat" Column to be visiable on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oobRx.png)

So how can i do that? Can anyone please help me?

Also you can get the folder on the link below if you want to look at it

[My Codes][3]

And my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Bare - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Top Bar -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row top-bar">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs clock"> 
          Saat
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9 control-panel">
          Tarih
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 4? Seems like there's 3 and 4 mixed in your code.

Comment: Yes i noticed that now you are saying) thanks a lot